# I want to show update on a button as well as save also

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to add a button on which i want to perform two different action of update as well as save but its not working, i had given if else for that also..

```
<button type="button" style="float:right" class="btn btn-sm bg-darkgreen">
  {{action}}
</button>
```

```
$scope.action = $routeParams.action;
$scope.data = localStorageService.get("formatdata");
$scope.action = "Save"
if ($scope.action == 'Edit' || $scope.action == 'Copy') {
    return(Update);
}
else {
    return(Save);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code

```js
$scope.buttonName = ($scope.action == "Edit" || $scope.action == "Copy" )?"Update":"Save";
```

```html
<button type="button" style="float:right" class="btn btn-sm bg-darkgreen">{{buttonName}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" style="float:right" class="btn btn-sm bg-darkgreen">{{buttonName}}</button>
```

```
$scope.action = $routeParams.action;
$scope.data = localStorageService.get("formatdata");
$scope.buttonName="Save";
($scope.action == 'Edit' || $scope.action == 'Copy') ? $scope.buttonName="Update" : $scope.buttonName="Save";
```